# How to enable tab auto completion linux subsystem windows 10

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have installed kali linux subsystem on my windows 10 machine. 
When ever i hit tab button in linux bash i hear some annoying sound and

> apt-get install ph

doesn't give me any suggestion of packages as in native debian terminal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably missing the "package name completion" package. I think it's called `bash-completion` on Debian.